# String elements in array with whitespaces in them being splitted?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the next array's elements to replace some strings in a file:

```
declare -a replacements=($name, $description, $date, $keywords)
```

By using the search terms in this array:

```
declare -a searchs=("a.name", "a.description", "a.date", "a.keywords")
```

The problem is that some variables (`description`, for example) have whitespaces in them:

```
declare description = "My name is Jonah"
```

Which casuses a weird behaviour on the next piece of code:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#searchs[@]}; i++))
do
    sed -i -e "s/${searchs[$i]}/${replacements[$i]}/g" "./${directory}/data.txt"
done
```

The for loops uses every word in the string as a replacement instead of the whole string.

Is there a way to fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to quote elements before inserting them in the array.

I suppose that also you may NOT separate your elements with a comma.

```
declare -a replacements=("$name" "$description" "$date" "$keywords")
```

Comment: Commas where an error of mine while writing the code in here. I didn't want to use the actual code. Either way, the quoting is indeed the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should quotes in your declaration of array with shell variables:

```
declare -a replacements=("$name" "$description" "$date" "$keywords")
```

Also note that there must not be commas in shell array initialization.

You can check array content using:

```
declare -p replacements
```